# Edit link returns at first routes error. But after press enter it works in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource

```
resources :posts
```

So, I write

```
<%= link_to 'Изменить', edit_post_path(posts.id), method: :edit %>
```

And it opens the url:

```
http://178.62.102.154:3000/posts/3522/edit
```

And returns `No route matches [POST] "/posts/3522/edit"`. But then I press on url and ENTER it opens. Why it doesn't open from the first time???

Answer (score 0):

You should write it :

```
<%= link_to 'Изменить', edit_post_path(posts.id), method: :get %>
```

`method:` options takes the **HTTP** *verbs* as *symbols*.

> [**Resource** routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html) allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code:

```
resources :posts
```

The above code created with all other actions, the `#edit` action as :

```
# GET edit_post_url(:id => 1)
def edit
  # return an HTML form for editing a specific post
end
```

If you don't pass the value of the `method:` option, it is by default `POST`, as per the [`#link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation.. So, your code hits the link using `POST` method, but the route file defined the action using `GET` method. That's why you got the error as you mentioned in the post.